# GCD Grand Central Dispatch async crash when finish

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, grand-central-dispatch

in my app I need to use Grand Central Dispatch (CGD) to perform a lot of operations (resize a set of images) in background.

I have the class `EngineViewController` that is the rootViewController of the app:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
EngineViewController * engineVc = [[EngineViewController alloc]init];
self.window.rootViewController = engineVC;
```

In `viewDidAppear` method of `engineVC` i have the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //this method resize a set of image and save them in Document Folder of the app
        //this method needs about 40 seconds to perform all operations
        [[JSONParser sharedJSONParser]writeToDiskResizedImage]; 
        NSLog(@"Finished");

    });

}
```

After the method `[[JSONParser sharedJSONParser]writeToDiskResizedImage]` returns, `NSLog` prints the message in the console and the app crash. All my project is ARC, execpt for `JSONParser` class. In console there isn't an error message; I have only this:

[image]

The code execute from `[[JSONParser sharedJSONParser]writeToDiskResizedImage]` is the following:

```
CGFloat screenScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

NSString * imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:imageName ofType:nil];
//UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

CGSize newImageSize = [image resizeImageSettingWidth:(kArticleImageWidth * screenScale)];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImageSize);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newImageSize.width,newImageSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage =UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

if (image) {
    [image release];
}

NSData *jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.9f);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory

NSString * newImageName;
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] &&
    ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0)) {

    newImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-article@2x.jpg", [imageName stringByDeletingPathExtension]];

}
else {

    newImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-article.jpg", [imageName stringByDeletingPathExtension]];
}

NSLog(@"newImageName %@", newImageName);

NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:newImageName]; //Add the file name

[jpegData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file

if (newImage) {
    [newImage release];
}

if (jpegData) {
    [jpegData release];

}
```

Comment: Did you try to set up Exception breakpoint ?

Comment: If you set it you should see deassambly code, and see where the problem is.

Comment: If not open Instruments and search for NSZombie, you're trying to release, dealocated object, ARC could insert somewhere autorelease and when you release somthing ARC is releasing it second time.

Comment: Considering this is happening in a background thread, I would suspect something you are calling is not thread safe.